# Spreadsheet::ParseExcel building an array or hash

Tags: perl

I am new to [`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`](http://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel). I have a space-delimited file which I opened in Microsoft Excel and saved it as a XLS file.

I installed `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` and used the example code in documentation to print the contents of the file. My objective is to build an array of some of the data to write to a database. I just need a little help building the array -- writing to a database I'll figure out later.

I'm having a hard time understanding this module -- I did read the documentation, but because of my inexperience I'm unable to understand it.

Below is the code I'm using for the output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse( 'file.xls' );

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {

        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
            print "Value       = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";
            print "Unformatted = ", $cell->unformatted(), "\n";
            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And here is some of the output

```
Row, Col    = (0, 0)
Value       = NewRecordFlag
Unformatted = NewRecordFlag

Row, Col    = (0, 1)
Value       = AgencyName
Unformatted = AgencyName

Row, Col    = (0, 2)
Value       = CredentialIdnt
Unformatted = CredentialIdnt

Row, Col    = (0, 3)
Value       = ContactIdnt
Unformatted = ContactIdnt

Row, Col    = (0, 4)
Value       = AgencyRegistryCardNumber
Unformatted = AgencyRegistryCardNumber

Row, Col    = (0, 5)
Value       = Description
Unformatted = Description

Row, Col    = (0, 6)
Value       = CredentialStatusDescription
Unformatted = CredentialStatusDescription

Row, Col    = (0, 7)
Value       = CredentialStatusDate
Unformatted = CredentialStatusDate

Row, Col    = (0, 8)
Value       = CredentialIssuedDate
Unformatted = CredentialIssuedDate
```

My objective is to build an array of `CredentialIssuedDate`, `AgencyRegistryCardNumber`, and `AgencyName`. Once I grasp the concept of doing that, I can go to town with this great module.

Comment: If you started out with a space-separated text file, then why don't you use that? It'll probably be simpler than parsing an Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of something that should work for you. It builds an array `@rows` of arrays of the three field values you want for each worksheet, and displays each result using `Data::Dumper`. I haven't been able to test it, but it looks right and does compile

It starts by building a hash `%headers` that relates the column header strings to the column number, based on the first row in each worksheet.

Then the second row onwards is processed, extracting the cells in the columns named in the `@wanted` array, and putting their values in the array `@row`, which is pushed onto `@rows` as each one is accumulated

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Data::Dumper;

my @wanted = qw/
    CredentialIssuedDate
    AgencyRegistryCardNumber
    AgencyName
/;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new;
my $workbook = $parser->parse('file.xls');

if ( not defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error, ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range;
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range;

    my %headers;

    for my $col ( $col_min, $col_max ) {
        my $header = $worksheet->get_cell($row_min, $col)->value;
        $headers{$header} = $col;
    }

    my @rows;

    for my $row ( $row_min + 1 .. $row_max ) {

        my @row;

        for my $name ( @wanted ) {
            my $col = $headers{$name};
            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($row, $col);
            push @row, $cell ? $cell->value : "";
        }

        push @rows, \@row;
    }

    print Dumper \@rows;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at ./flow.pl line 42.` Will you explain the steps to the solution? Thanks.

Comment: Now it is printing: `$VAR1 = [
          [
            ''
          ],
          [
            ''
          ],
          [
            ''
          ],
          [
            ''
          ],
          [
            ''
          ],
          [
            ''
          ],`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using the `Spreadsheet::BasicReadNamedCol` module

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Spreadsheet::BasicReadNamedCol;

my $xlsFileName = 'shit.xls';
my @columnHeadings = (
'AgencyName',
'eMail',
'PhysicalAddress1',
'PhysicalAddress2'
);

my $ss = new Spreadsheet::BasicReadNamedCol($xlsFileName) ||
die "Could not open '$xlsFileName': $!";
$ss->setColumns(@columnHeadings);

# Print each row of the spreadsheet in the order defined in
# the columnHeadings array
my $row = 0;
while (my $data = $ss->getNextRow())
{
   $row++;
   print join('|', $row, @$data), "\n";
}
```